# Create worklow dispatch event for repository in ORGANIZATION

Tags: github-actions, github-api

I keep getting 404(Not Found) when trying to make a request to create a dispatch event.
The repository is inside an Organization and is private

```
curl -L \
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <personal_token>"\
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/<organization>/<repository>/actions/workflows/<workflow_id>/dispatches \
  -d '{"ref":"<branch>"}'
```

I'm making the request using the command above.

The token has the following permissions:

> Repository access: All repositories
>
> Permissions: Actions(Read and Write)

Comment: curl command looks correct. Make sure you add `on: workflow_dispatch` in your workflow file.